# SwiftUI & Scheduled timers

Tags: swiftui

I'm building an app with SwiftUI with a stop watch functionality.
The TimedSession class has a `var timer: Timer` computed property like this:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.01, repeats: true) { timer in
            guard let time = self.currentTime else {
                print("no current time")
                return
            }

            if self.status != .running {
                timer.invalidate()

                return
            }

            time.duration += 1

            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }
```

this works well until I start to interact with other parts of the UI, like a scrollview. It's not just that the timer UI is locked, but the block: callbck on scheduledTimer isn't being executed.

What's the best way to put the callback block into the background? I've tried with GCD but no good so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scheduled `Timer` works by default in `.default` run loop mode, but during user interaction, like scrolling, a run loop works in different tracking mode.

The solution is set up `Timer` for *all* standard modes, named `.common`, like below

```
// just create non attached timer
let timer = Timer(timeInterval: 0.01, repeats: true) { timer in
            guard let time = self.currentTime else {
                print("no current time")
                return
            }

            if self.status != .running {
                timer.invalidate()

                return
            }

            time.duration += 1

            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }

...

init() {
   // Start timer in run-loop on common modes
   RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .common)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - that does indeed solve the issue with the scrollview. I'm still seeing the timer stop when the app is put into the background in the simulator (initial question propbably not clear enough - sorry). 

Is a RunLoop the way around that? I've also tried wrapping the timer block with DispatchQueue.global/DispatchQueue.main closures - but when the app is minimised the timer is stopped

Comment: Timers do not work in the background, unless you have an acceptable background mode enabled.  They don't give us one for just timers.  A local notification is used to have a timer go off at a specific time.  For stop watch type timers, save the start time, and in the .onAppear (or viewWillAppear with UIKit), calculate the minutes / seconds or hours based on the current time from that start time.  It'll look like your stopwatch was running all along, even though it was doing nothing when the app went into the background.

Comment: Thanks @ShadowDES I'd assumed timers would've worked with background processing enabled. Thanks for the help!